# Max Sum Of Integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

EDIT: solved! I was treating negative numbers test case as 0, instead of having the output be negative as well. thanks for the help!

Here is the challenge description: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/17/
I keep getting a partially solved score. I want to know why. As in my eyes, this code works. And I believe that it is O(N) time. Thanks for looking!

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    int max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            return a;
        else return b;
    }


    int maxSubArray(vector<int> values)
    {
        int max_so_far = values[0];
        int curr_max = values[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i)
        {
            curr_max = max(values[i], curr_max + values[i]);
            max_so_far = max(max_so_far, curr_max);
        }
        return max_so_far;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        std::vector<vector<int> > Values; //to hold the values of the stock price change
        ifstream file(argv[1]);
        std::string line; //for the txt file input
        int value = 0; //for holding the value of stock change

        while (std::getline(file, line)) 
        {
            int pos = 0;
            if(line.length() == 0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                std::istringstream iss(line);
                std::vector<int> list; // temporary list of values to be pushed back into the 2-d vector
                while (iss >> value)
                {   
                    list.push_back(value);  
                }

                Values.push_back(list);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < Values.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << maxSubArray(Values[i]);
            cout << endl;
        }
    /*  
        cout << " Printing the values : " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < Values.size(); ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < Values[j].size(); ++k)
                cout << Values[j][k] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    */
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is it me, or does the original problem (CodeEval #17) make just about zero sense? I can't even combine the sample input in my mind to produce the sample output.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Makes sense to me. For example one, add the sequence starting at 2 and ending at 5 to get 8; for example two, add the entire sequence to get 12.

Comment: @DanielWagner I see it now. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think the original problem as presented at CodeEval is really poorly worded, though.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz For what it's worth, I totally agree that it's very poorly worded.

Comment: A concrete test-case that this code fails on: if all entries in the list are negative, the maximal sum should *probably* be the empty subsequence, with sum 0, rather than the one-entry subsequence with negative sum.

Comment: @DanielWagner I fixed the case when the entries are all negative. And I'm still getting a partial solution. The updated code is below.

Answer (score 1):

so I swapped out some code now. I get better score but I it's still a partial.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;
}


int maxSubArray(vector<int> values)
{
    int max_so_far = values[0];
    int curr_max = values[0];
    if (curr_max < 0) 
    {
        curr_max = 0;           
        max_so_far = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        curr_max = max(values[i], curr_max + values[i]);
        curr_max = max(curr_max, 0);
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, curr_max);
    }
    return max_so_far;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::vector<vector<int> > Values; //to hold the values of the stock price change
    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    std::string line; //for the txt file input
    std::string token; //for the subtring that will be converted from char to int
    int value = 0; //for holding the value of stock change
    int count = 0;// for holding how many total cases

    while (!file.eof()) 
    {
        int pos = 0;
        getline(file, line);
        if(line.length() == 0)
            continue;
        else
        {

            std::vector<int> list; // temporary list of values to be pushed back into the 2-d vector

            while ((pos = line.find(",")) != std::string::npos )
            {
                token = line.substr(0,pos);
                value = atoi(token.c_str());
                line.erase(0, pos + 1); 
                list.push_back(value);  
            }
            value = atoi(line.c_str());
            list.push_back(value);

            Values.push_back(list);

            ++count;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < Values.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << maxSubArray(Values[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << " Printing the values : " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < Values.size(); ++j)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < Values[j].size(); ++k)
            cout << Values[j][k] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cant figure out a test case for which this code wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you passing the vector by value here?

   `int maxSubArray(vector<int> values)`

   That looks like a significant optimization opportunity.
2. I think you don't read the problem exactly right. When they say 'all contiguous sub ararys', they mean you have to take the max over all `i` and`j` of `for(idx = i; i < j; ++i) { total += vec[idx]; }`. Right now your code basically assumes `i = 0` which isn't what you are supposed to do.

   Just from looking at the output examples they provide, I can see that your code isn't going to give the answer that they expect.

Comment: Are you sure about your complaint in (2)? It looks like a pretty minor variation on the algorithm described [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem). In particular, the line `curr_max = max(values[i], curr_max + values[i]);` is the part of the code that may choose (in your notation) an `i > 0`.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I still think his code is wrong, the link you posted is quite interesting and I didn't know this trick. But doing `max(value[i], curr_max + values[i])` instead of `max(0, curr_max + values[i])` sounds like it cant possibly work and would be slower anyways

Answer (score 0):

it seems right, the only thing I can think of is that when the list gets long, your result can overflow, so change int to long long.

Answer (score 0):

Besides technical optimizations suggested in other answers, concerning the algorithm, i think a little fix can make your algorithm work. When curr_max drops to a negative value, due to encountering a negative integer that exceeds curr_max, you can simply drop all the previous integers including the current value and start over. This fix is simple, you can add one line to your loop like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < values.size(); ++i)
{
    curr_max = max(values[i], curr_max + values[i]);
    curr_max = max(curr_max, 0); // <---------------- add this line
    max_so_far = max(max_so_far, curr_max);
}
```